# Check two Textbox Values (JavaScript)

Tags: c#

```
Validate the Textbox to find if the values are different.
```

Textbox1.text!=textbox2.Text -- Valid

Textbox1.text==textbox2.Text -- InValid

Accept Validation Only if the Values are different.

Comment: It looks like you've already got the code you need. What's the problem? Also, we have no idea whether this is ASP.NET, WinForms etc. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this:

bool someVariable = Textbox1.text!=textbox2.Text ? true : false;

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid = false;

if(Textbox1.Text.Equals(Textbox2.Text))
{
    valid = true;
}

//Do something with valid
```